# code igniter session destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why codeigniter session destroyed after page re direction,
this is my auto load conf
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session');
my login controller code is

```
$result = $this->Loginmodel->verify_user($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));//returned as db->result()


        if ($result !== False) {
            //person has an account
                foreach ($result as $obj) {
                $user_id = $obj->user_id;
                $userdesignation = $obj->user_designation;

                $user_access = $obj->user_cpanelpass;

            }


            $sessiondata = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'username' => $username,
                'loginuser' => TRUE,
                'userdesignaton' => $userdesignation,


            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);


            $sessiondata1 = array(
                'shopname' => 'abc',
                'shopplace' => 'xyz'
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata1);

            $ipaddress = $this->ipaddress();
            $this->Loginmodel->loginloginsert($username, $ipaddress);
            redirect('home');
```

this is working fine in my system but not working in another system .The session is destroyed automatically when redirected to home or any other controller.

Comment: Check the values of `$config['sess_driver']` and `$config['sess_save_path']` variables in `config/config.php`. If the session stores in files then ensure that the folder has proper permission to write session data.